# Error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gobject-2.0.lib'

Tags: rust, gtk, rust-cargo, gtk-rs

I am trying to build a gtk-4 GUI application with the Rust in VScode, but I am unable to because I can't build my project. What could be the problem? How do I fix it?

Here's the error
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gobject-2.0.lib'

My Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "my-gtk-app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.4.7", package = "gtk4", features = ["v4_6"]}
```

Comment: Have you installed the Gtk 4 development package?

Comment: @Jmb Yes, I do have GTK 4 installed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Building the project as an administrator fixed the problem.

Comment: If that really is the case, then it sounds like you have some bad permissions. I'd seriously look into that. It could cause lots of other issues.