# Cannot build gtk4-rs based cargo, build fails with linking error "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gobject-2.0.lib'"

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk-rs

I am trying to build a hello world project to see if gtk4-rs is working correctly, which always fails at creating the binaries. The rest of the build seems to fine (tried to run cargo clean and cargo check a couple of times, those do not produce any errors). My Cargo.toml just uses the version specified in the crate:

```
[dependencies]
gtk4 = "0.4.8"
```

My error is exactly the same as the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968209/error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-gobject-2-0-lib), but running the cargo build in an admin powershell also fails with the same error.

I am on Win 11 and I've followed the installation instructions linked to by GTK themselves, https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild.

The linking error seems to indicate that gobject-2.0.lib is missing:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gobject-2.0.lib'
```

(Full error message (with redacted user directory) [on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DKnW6t3g))

That file is found at c:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\lib, which is the default location for an installation produced by gvsbuild, as far as I can tell (I haven't messed with the files at all).
Both c:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\lib and c:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\bin are part of the path, restarting the machine did not seem to fix anything in this regard either.

I have not found anything close to helpful on the internet, so any pointers to what could be wrong here would be great.

Comment: After poking around for a bit more, I think the the problem lies in the fact that - for some reason - in the LIBPATH for several files is incorrectly set to "/LIBPATH:C:gtk-buildgtkx64release/lib", which should(?) be "/LIBPATH:C:\\gtk-build\\gtk\\x64\\release\\lib". I cannot see why this occurs, what causes this or how I could fix this.